# Does Amazon RDS support other storage types than EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In the RDS FAQ it says, "Amazon RDS uses EBS volumes for database and log storage". Is there any way to get RDS to store its data on another kind of storage? I'm asking because EBS has a reputation for being kind of slow.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense to use DB with ephemeral storage as losing your instance will mean losing your data. Therefore, using EBS with its better durability is preferred.

You can use Provisioned IOPS for your EBS and with a combination of RAID0 on multiple EBS with P-IOPS on "EBS Optimized" instances you can get up to 10,000 IOPS which is rather enough for most DB applications. See more about Provisioned IOPS in RDS here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.ProvisionedIOPS.html

See how to improved the performance of EBS here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSPerformance.html